# restrict viewer js url from accessing file without logging in

Tags: javascript, php, fat-free-framework

I need to restrict accessing files from the server if the user is not logged in.

I am using ViewerJS to preview files and I can access the uploaded files from the server just by entering the url.

```
http://localhost/gbdportal-new/ViewerJS/#../uploads/2138970950.pdf
```

I tried performing a check when the user hits that route :

```
$f3->route('GET ViewerJS/*', function()
{
    /* if user not logged in.. no access
    */
});
```

But viewerJS directly renders the file without passing through this route check [I guess].

How can I prevent users from accessing the file without logging in?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: PHP doesn't care about `#` or anything after. The actual path is just `/gbdportal-new/ViewerJS/` no matter what you put after the `#`. What if you remove the `*`? You also seem to have path segments before. Tried `$f3->route('GET gbdportal-news/ViewerJS/', function ()`?

Comment: yeah..it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your server configuration, if your server detect that the requested URL is a file , it will directly fetch the file and will not execute your code.

The best way to do what you are trying to achieve is to create a new route in your PHP code that will check that the user is connected and then open the file to send it to the client.

the code would look like

```
$f3->route('GET getFile/@file', function()
{
    if( /*the user is logged in*/){
        $fileName = $f3->get('PARAMS.file')

        header("Content-type:application/pdf");

        readfile("uploads/$file.pdf");
    }else{
        //return a 403 error
    }
});
```

Now you can put `http://localhost/gbdportal-new/ViewerJS/#../getFile/2138970950` in JsViewer and it will not be able to get the file unless the user is logged in

I hope I answered your question, have a good day

Comment: Have you used the viewerJS before??

Comment: I looked at the doc, If I understand correctly it will fetch the file having the URL behind the '#..' part, so if you use `http://localhost/gbdportal-new/ViewerJS/#../getFile/2138970950` it will in fact fetch the file at `http://localhost/gbdportal-new/getFile/2138970950` thus executing the PHP code and performing the authentication, am I right?

Comment: The web server doesn't translate that URL to the real file path (nether does PHP) since it's uses a hash to point to the actual file. The web server only checks if the folder `ViewerJS` exists (since that is the last part of the actual URL). So the OP is trying to protect the actual URL that's using ViewerJS.

Comment: I know it's not the server that does that automatically, it's JsViewer that uses that hash to then retrieve the content, if you look in the console on the JsViewer example page, the code `<iframe src="/ViewerJS/#../demo/ohm2013.odp"></iframe>` load JsViewer, then JsVeiwer fetch the file `/demo/ohm2013.odp`. So if you hide that file behind a PHP controller it will allow you to control its access.